# Constraint null y dni

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito un `constraint` que haga que solo se puedan insertar los valores **NULL** o un **DNI** válido (de España). No sé como añadir el que también valga el valor null, dejo mi constraint para ver si pueden terminarlo.
Gracias.

```
ALTER TABLE CITAS ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DNI_CITAS CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(
DNI_PACIENTE,'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta establecer la condición del `NULL`

```
ALTER TABLE CITAS ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DNI_CITAS CHECK (
      REGEXP_LIKE(DNI_PACIENTE,'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]') OR DNI_PACIENTE IS NULL
);
```

También puedes escribir la expresión regular de forma más compacta:

```
ALTER TABLE CITAS ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DNI_CITAS CHECK (
     REGEXP_LIKE(DNI_PACIENTE,'\d{8}[A-Z]') OR DNI_PACIENTE IS NULL
);
```

O incluso puedes resolver todo como expresión regular:

```
ALTER TABLE CITAS ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DNI_CITAS CHECK (
     REGEXP_LIKE(NVL(DNI_PACIENTE, 'NULL'),'\d{8}[A-Z]|NULL')
);
```